# Why my content-not-editable div allows content edition?

Tags: html, contenteditable, document-body

I have an HTML like this:

```
<html>
  <body contenteditable='true'>

    <div contenteditable='false'>
      Some Text
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

But the text inside the div is editable. I tested it on jsfiddle and it works the way I need.

Comment: Are you saying it works right on jsFiddle, but not on your own site? Could you provide links to both?

Comment: It's actually not a site, it's a HTML/JavaScript based text editor in a OSX App. Here's a gist with the code:https://gist.github.com/gabrielvincent/8e987bae88208bbfbef8
Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielvincent/PZke8/

Answer (score -1):

I think, you need to add `contenteditable="false"` for `h2` tag also. because `h2` `tag inherit`  the `contenteditable` property of body. so add `contenteditable="false"`  property  to `h2` tag.

```
      <div class="heading-box-text" contenteditable="false">H2</div>

    <h2 class="headingAlreadyInsideContainer" contenteditable="false">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </h2>
```

**Note**: This code taken from you git resource. what you have added in the above link.

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work for me. When I inspect the element, the value of `contenteditable` appears automatically between quotes. This is how I create the div: http://i.imgur.com/kqedRdT.png . And this is how I it appears when I inspect it: http://i.imgur.com/GCUXcio.png

Comment: @chandu can you provide some authoritative source to back up your claim that attribute values in quotes can be problematic? All other sources say that attribute values _without_ quotes can be problematic.